# reverse zip 2 lists (without using zip or reverse)

Tags: list, haskell

I want to write a function that takes two lists as arguments and creates a list with a pair from each list consecutively, but in reverse.
for example:

```
reversezipLists [1, 2, 3] ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

would produce `[('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 1)]`.

Here is my attempt:

```
reversezipLists :: [a] -> [b] -> [(b,a)]
reversezipLists [] [] = []
reversezipLists [] ys = []
reversezipLists xs [] = []
reversezipLists (x:xs) (y:ys) = (y,x) : reversezipLists xs ys
```

the problem is the output of my code is: `[('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]`. How can I reverse it?

Comment: This doesn't looks like Racket (Haskell?). In any case, one way to do it is to use an accumulator. Read about it at https://htdp.org/2020-8-1/Book/part_six.html

Comment: what should the output for `reversezipLists [1, 2, 3] ['a', 'b']` be? `[('b',2),('a',1)]` or `[('b',3),('a',2)]`?

Comment: the size must be the same, so it supposed to show an error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an accumulator:

```
reversezipLists :: [a] -> [b] -> [(b, a)]
reversezipLists = go [] where
  go acc [] _ = acc
  go acc _ [] = acc
  go acc (h1:t1) (h2:t2) = go ((h2, h1) : acc) t1 t2
```

Bonus points: the function is tail recursive. The basic idea is that we append new pairs to the `acc` during the left-to-right traverse through the lists. The stackish nature of Haskell lists makes the result reversed. Note that it will truncate longer list.

---

If you want to throw an error when the lists' lengths don't match, you can play a bit with patterns:

```
reversezipLists :: [a] -> [b] -> [(b, a)]
reversezipLists = go [] where
  go acc [] [] = acc
  go acc (h1:t1) (h2:t2) = go ((h2, h1) : acc) t1 t2
  go _ _ _ = error "lists' sizes don't match"
```

Comment: [it depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64629257/reverse-zip-2-lists-without-using-zip-or-reverse#comment114279125_64629257) on *when* that `reverse` is implied to be done, *before* or *after* the zipping. it's unclear, but the other option seems at least just as likely as the one you've picked.

Comment: Yeah, important note

Comment: @radrow how can I check if the lists have the same size or it will prin an error

Comment: Updated answer to cover this case

Answer (score 1):

```
r (x:xs) (y:ys) = (r xs ys) ++ [(y,x)]
r [] [] = []
```

r [1, 2, 3] ['a', 'b', 'c'] = [('c',3),('b',2),('a',1)]

it works only on lists of the same length

Comment: now remove the `++` in your code. just delete it. this means `r` now accepts 3 arguments. call the third one `zs`. call the new function `r3`. the call `r3 a b zs` represents `r a b ++ zs`. this means `r3 (x:xs) (y:ys) zs = r (x:xs) (y:ys) ++ zs = (r xs ys ++ [(y,x)]) ++ zs = r xs ys ++ ([(y,x)] ++ zs) = r3 xs ys ([(y,x)] ++ zs)`, because list appending is associative. and there you have it, same algorithm, but linear, instead of quadratic as your code is. Haskell on its own is not smart enough to do this transformation though. (this is famous trick from Richard Bird, from 1980s I think)